# How to open .doc files natively in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiwebview, doc

I need to create an application to open .doc files natively in iPhone. But I can't find any code online.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView will do it, just load it up as you would a regular web page.

Comment: But I am supposed to open the files natively, in my application. Without the use f the UIWebView

Comment: Why are you so against using a UIWebView, you can store the files locally and open them. It's all built into iOS

Comment: There appears to be some confusion between UIWebView and Safari here. You can incorporate a UIWebView into your own iOS application.